# Windows 8 Kiosk Mode For "Non Windows" Applications

Tags: windows-8, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I have an external kiosk application that I'm trying to run it on tablet computer which has Windows 8 OS.
The thing is, that Windows 8 doesn't allow to use any external applications in kiosk mode. Only applications that based on Win 8 are allowed.

The problem with my kiosk application that while running you can drag it with the finger and the task bar and the desktop background are revealed and I don't want that to happen.
I want it to be locked to the screen without any option to move.

The application starts automatically when the win 8 goes up.

1)I tried to search at the registry to cancel part of the touch options. Without any actual result. There are few options to cancel some of the windows widgets at the left and right corners of the screen or cancel the touch option at all.

2)I've got the option to use a 3rd party applications, but I'm trying to prevent it for now.

Comment: When you say "you can drag it with the finger and the task bar and the desktop background are revealed", are you referring to edge gestures or a movable window? What language/framework is your application written in (or is it a third-party app)?

Comment: If your window runs full screen on top of all other applications and you disable edge gestures, you should have an app that fully obscures the desktop and taskbar. Worst case, [you can make your desired app run instead of the Explorer shell](http://superuser.com/a/435890/119615) and there literally won't be a desktop or taskbar to see.

Comment: I'm talking about the movement of the application. Let's say that I can move the background of the application up and down, the whole thing moves, which I want to prevent. Not talking about the gestures. I have an 3rd party application

Answer (score 0):

Forget about windows internal kiosk mode as nightmare - it not works as expected and you can't change this. Create new user 'kiosk' and use next registry key for your app:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"Shell"="C:\\full\\path\\to\\your\\application.exe>"
```

And configure autologin for this user:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon] 
"AutoAdminLogon"="1"
"ForceAutoLogon"="1"
"DefaultUserName"="kiosk"
"DefaultDomainName"="<place here pc hostname>"
"DefaultPassword"=""
```

And you will get the result you want.